# iOS Simulator says "The simulated application quit" when using Network Home Directories

Tags: macos, xcode

If I'm logged in to an account using Network Home Directories, I get the following error when I try to build and run an iOS application in Xcode 4:

```
6/20/12 5:33:22.818 PM Xcode: Error launching simulated application: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=1 "The simulated application quit." UserInfo=0x402da70a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The simulated application quit., DTiPhoneSimulatorUnderlyingErrorCodeKey=-1}
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Create an `iPhone Simulator` folder on a local disk, and link to it from the network home:

```
rm -Rf "~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator"
mkdir "/Volumes/Local/$USER/.iPhoneSimulator"
ln -s "/Volumes/Local/$USER/.iPhoneSimulator" "~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator"
```